# RxJS of operator always returns cold observable

Tags: rxjs, observable

I was playing with RxJS to understand Hot and Cold Observables. However I am confused with the output below code gives :

```
const source$ = of(1,2,3,4).pipe(share());
source$.subscribe(i => console.log('first subscription',i)); 
setTimeout(() => source$.subscribe(j => console.log('second subscription',j)), 
2000);
```

Expected output is that first subscription prints 1 2 3,4 and second prints just 2,3,4 However both subscriptions put out 1,2,3,4.

When I replace "of" with interval it works correctly with and without using share() operator

Comment: `of` emits everything on subscription and then completes. `share()` unsubscribes from its source when it completes and creates a new Subject on another subscription.

Comment: thanks  @martin  got it now